# EF Core database filter

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). I am new to C# and need some help!

I am trying to add a feature to the GetUsers function to be able to get a list of "Users" associated with a "Company" in the else statement. The return type should be of type `List<UserDTO>` (which it is in the if statement).

However, the else statement returns a `List<User>`. How do I tell the database query to return a `List<UserDTO>`?

I get this build error:
*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestProj.Models.User>' to'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestProj.Models.UserDTO>>'*

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>> GetUsers(int? companyId)
    {
        if(companyId == null)
        {
            return await _context.Users.Select(x => UserToDTO(x)).ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return await _context.Users
                                        .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
                                        .ToListAsync(); 
        }
    }




 private static UserDTO UserToDTO(User user) =>
    new UserDTO
    {
        UserId = user.UserId,
        Name = user.Name,
        Email = user.Email,
        CompanyId = user.CompanyId
    };
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to Select to the UserDTO

```
      return await _context.Users
            .Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId)
            .Select(x => new UserDTO
             {
                 UserId = x.UserId,
                 Name = x.Name,
                 Email = x.Email,
                 CompanyId = x.CompanyId
             }).ToList();
```